# How do I check if something is an elem of a qw?

Tags: raku

According to the documentation `<a b c d e>` and `qw|a b c d e|` are similar, and furthermore they both make lists, which means they should be equivalent to `('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')`.

Why then am I not able to do this: `'2' (elem) <1 2 3 4 5>`?

`2 (elem) <1 2 3 4 5>` doesn't work either, but `'a' (elem) <a b c d e>` DOES.

What's going on? Shouldn't I be able to check the existence of the number like anything else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you do :

```
<1 2 3 4 5>.raku.say
```

You'll see that it creates a list of IntStr objects (which are objects that can be either a String or an Integer). When we put these in a set we get a Set of IntStr objects.

The problem is `(elem)` doesn't use smart-matching but equivalence and neither the `Int 1` or the `String "1"` are equivalent to `IntStr.new(1, "1")`. They do both smart-match with the IntStr...

You probably want to use `first` to find the needle :

```
defined <1 2 3 4 5>.first( 2, :k )
```

`first( $match, :k )` returns the index of the first matching item and `Nil` if there's no match. So we test to see if it's defined and if so our item exists.

Or you can cast your list to String ot Integers using a `map`.

```
2 (elem) <1 2 3 4 5>.map( *.Int )
```

Comment: What if I have a mixed list? `<a b c 1 2 3>` and want to check membership? will `.first` still work?

Comment: Yup. I just tested it in the command line `say defined <a b c 1 2 3 4 5>.first( 1, :k ) => True` `say defined <a b c 1 2 3 4 5>.first( "a", :k ) -> True` `say defined <a b c 1 2 3 4 5>.first( "d", :k ) => False` `say defined <a b c 1 2 3 4 5>.first( "7", :k ) => False`

Answer (score 9):

So first off `<…>` is actually the same as:

```raku
q:w:v < … >
```

Or more verbosely:

```raku
Q :single :words :val < … >
```

The `q` or `:single` is how you specify the semantics of single quotes.

```raku
'abc'
q 'abc'
Q :q 'abc'
Q :single 'abc'
```

The `:w` or `:words` specifies that you want the string to be split on whitespace.

```raku
Q :w     ' a b   c '    eqv    'a', 'b', 'c'
Q :words ' a b   c '    eqv    'a', 'b', 'c'
```

The `:v` or `:val` specifies that you want `val()` semantics.
Using `val` will turn a string representing a number into something that is both a string and a number.

```raku
Q :v   '123'
Q :val '123'
val( '123' )
IntStr.new( 123, '123' )
```

Note that you can combine `Q`, `q`, or `qq` with a single character option

```raku
qw 'a b'   =:=   q:w 'a b'  =:=  q:words 'a b'
qb 'a\n'   =:=   q:b 'a\n'  =:=  q:backslash 'a\n'
qs 'a$_'   =:=   q:s 'a$_'  =:=  q:scalar 'a$_'
```

(It is probably a bug that `qv''` doesn't work.)

---

At any rate `(elem)` and all Set/Bag/Mix operators deal with specific things, not generalities.

```raku
1.0    (elem)   1,2,3; # False
1      (elem)   1,2,3; # True
```

So if anything is different, those operators treat them as different things.

```raku
q:v '1'   (elem)   1; # False
q:v '1'   (elem)   IntStr.new(1,'1'); # True

<1>   (elem)   1; # False
<1>   (elem)   IntStr.new(1,'1'); # True
```

As we've established `<1>` wouldn't return an `Int`, it returns an `IntStr`.
An `IntStr` isn't exactly the same as an `Int` so it doesn't match an `Int`.

---

Presumably you want numeric things to only be numeric.

```raku
​< a b c 1 2 3 >.duckmap:  -> Numeric $_ { +$_ }
```

This goes through the list and anything that is already Numeric will get this function called on it.
The function does only one thing, call `prefix:« + »` which calls `.Numeric` on the value.

Since an `IntStr` is an `Int` which does `Numeric`, the function will be called on those values.

---

You may be wondering why `<…>` uses `val` semantics.

The reason is there is no way to know if you plan on giving it to a function that needs a `Str` or something `Numeric`.

```raku
sub foo ( Str ){}
sub bar ( Int ){}

foo <1>;
bar <1>;

foo 1;   # Failure
bar '1'; # Failure
```

Comment: Great explanation there Brad :) I mostly approached it in my normal fashion of some poking and some docs reading.

Answer (score 4):

> check if something is an element

The only coercion that `(elem)` applies is the minimum necessary to enable its right hand side argument to accept a set operation. It does not coerce at the element level and instead does strict comparison of values. So you must apply your own explicit coercion, for example:

```
'2' (elem) qw<1 2 3>                   ; # True
'2' (elem) ~«<1 2 3>                   ; # True
'2' (elem)   <1 2 3>».Str              ; # True
'2' (elem)   <1 2 3> .map: *.Str       ; # True

2   (elem) +«<1 2 3>                   ; # True
2   (elem)   <1 2 3>».Int              ; # True
2   (elem)   <1 2 3> .map: *.Int       ; # True

'2' (elem)   <a 2> .duckmap: *.Int     ; # False
2   (elem)   <a 2> .duckmap: *.Int     ; # True
'a' (elem)   <a 2> .duckmap: *.Int     ; # False

'2' (elem)   <a 2> .duckmap: *.Str     ; # True
2   (elem)   <a 2> .duckmap: *.Str     ; # False
'a' (elem)   <a 2> .duckmap: *.Str     ; # True
```

[`«`/`»`](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Hyper_operators) distribute an operation to the leaves of their tree or list argument(s). For example, `+«` distributes a prefix `+`, which coerces its argument to a number.

`duckmap` is somewhat similar to `«`/`»`; one major difference is that it just continues if an operation doesn't apply. That is to say, a trial bind (function call) is attempted for each element; if the type signature matches, the function is called and its return value(s) replace that element, otherwise the element is just retained in the result as is.

Comment: Great as always Raiph and I didn't know about duckmap until today. :)